# Why is the meaning of bigotry/bigotto different in italian language?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

According to Google, **bigotry** is:

obstinate or unreasonable attachment to a belief, opinion, or faction, in particular prejudice against a person or people on the basis of their membership of a particular group.
"the difficulties of combating prejudice and bigotry"

While, still according to Google, **bigotto** means:

Chi assiduamente e scrupolosamente osserva le pratiche del culto senza afferrarne l'intima essenza religiosa; bacchettone, pinzochero.

It seems like in italian the meaning is strictly related to religion, while in english it has a "wider" meaning.

Comment: May I suggest not to take “Google” as a source. It isn't: it shows excerpts from all kinds of website, from good academical sources to whoever's rants. So please check what you are actually quoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer, but I'm not sure what is exactly the question here. It can't be “Why is the meaning of bigotto different in Italian language”, because it's not “different”: it's what it is.

*Bigotto* comes from French *bigot*, in origin a pejorative term of abuse with which Normans were called, perhaps (but this is contested) from their Old English phrase *bī God*, that is *by God*. So probably the meaning comes from attributing to Normans a religiosity that was only apparent, not truly felt.

Whatever its precise origin, French *bigot* and its derivations, as Italian *bigotto* and English *bigot*, had originally (and in the French and Italian case still have) this meaning of “a sanctimonious person, a religious hypocrite, holier-than-thou”.

<sub>Why in English it has evolved toward different nuances is beyond the scope of this StackExchange. Those about English language might be able to help.</sub>

Comment: It is different, the common definition of bigotry in english is different from the italian one, I personally don't know about languages. Just had this question as I noticed an uncommon use of the word bigotry in some english videos, so I was wondering and noticed that the definition according to multiple dictionaries is different.

Comment: @SyncroIT: I see, thanks for clarifying. I'm afraid this site and my own knowledge can't help about the successive development of the word in English, after it borrowed _bigot_ from French.

Comment: @SyncroIT - the etymology, and possible semantic changes of the term bigotry in English can  be asked on https://english.stackexchange.com if you like. But please show your research when posting.